# Remove duplicates in a list of XYZ points

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

```
Mylist.GroupBy(x => new{x.X, x.Y}).Select(g => g.First()).ToList<XYZ>();
```

The above code works fine for me. I only want to compare the points based on the round(5) of the point component.

For example `x.X = 16.838974347323224` should be only compared as `x.X = 16.83897` because I experienced some inaccuracy after the round 5. Any suggestions?

**Solution:**

```
Mylist.GroupBy(x => new { X = Math.Round(x.X,5), Y = Math.Round(x.Y,5) })
               .Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
```

Comment: The issue seems pretty straight forward - what have you tried, and where exactly are you having problems?

Comment: Just add the corresponding Rounding into the `new { x.X, ... }`

Comment: some duplicates have been deleted where  the the 3 components x,y,z for the two points are typically the same. but when for example if x= 1.1111111111109 and x = 1.1111111111108 , the two points remain so I'm asking if I can add a round condition in the same statement above!

Comment: `GroupBy(x => new{ X = Math.Round(x.X, 5), Y = Math.Round(x.Y, 5), Z = Math.Round(x.Z, 5)})...`

Comment: Thank you @RubensFarias , you solved it nicely.

Comment: Thank you @LarsKristensen for your interest also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do so use `Math.Round`:

```
var result = Mylist.GroupBy(x => new { X = Math.Round(x.X,5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero), Y = Math.Round(x.Y,5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) })
                   .Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
```

However if what you want is to remove duplicates then instead of `GroupBy` go for one of these:

1. `Select` rounded and then `Distinct`:

   ```
   var result = Mylist.Select(item => new XYZ { X = Math.Round(item.X,5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero), 
                                                Y = Math.Round(item.Y,5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)})
                      .Distinct().ToList();
   ```
2. `Distinct` and override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` - (equals will do the rounding) - wouldn't suggest
3. `Distinct` and implement a custom `IEqualityComparer`:

   ```
   public class RoundedXyzComparer : IEqualityComparer<XYZ>
   {
       public int RoundingDigits { get; set; }
       public RoundedXyzComparer(int roundingDigits)
       {
          RoundingDigits = roundingDigits;
       }

       public bool Equals(XYZ x, XYZ y)
       {
          return Math.Round(x.X, RoundingDigits, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) == Math.Round(y.X, RoundingDigits, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) && 
                 Math.Round(x.Y,RoundingDigits, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) == Math.Round(y.Y, RoundingDigits, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
       }

       public int GetHashCode(XYZ obj)
       {
          return Math.Round(obj.X, RoundingDigits, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).GetHashCode() ^
                 Math.Round(obj.Y, RoundingDigits, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).GetHashCode();
       }
    }

    //Use:
    myList.Distinct(new RoundedXyzComparer(5));
   ```

Comment: The distinct didn't work at the beginning  and I feel the Comparer a bit confusing as it caused an error where I passed it to list.Extinct(comparer).tolist()

Comment: @IbrahemHamdyNaeem - Checked the the first and last options now -they work :)

Comment: Yes the first one solved it as I updated! I begin to love this site, it's amazing.

Comment: This isn't mathematically correct to use `Math.Round(x.X, 5)`. You might have two values that are very very very close to each other, but one is on one side of the round and the other on the other. Then all of a sudden you have two incredibly close numbers being considered separate numbers.

Comment: @Enigmativity - true - added the , `MidpointRounding` parameter

Comment: A little bit late to party but I don't get the downvote. The answer *is* useful. If you have anything to add, you can just post a comment for improvement.

Comment: @GiladGreen - It's rounding in general that's the problem. It's nothing to do with `MidpointRounding`. This is a bad answer to the problem because it uses rounding.

Comment: @Enigmativity - But why? after all what he wants is to round 5 and to distinct that - so as far as the answer to the question that is the answer.

Comment: @GiladGreen - The OP wants to remove duplicates. Rounding creates the situation where two very close numbers are retained because the fall on the wrong side of the rounding. It's not the right solution.

Comment: @Enigmativity - It is fine for you to think like that but this is what he wanted: _I only want to compare the points based on the round(5) of the point component_

Comment: @GiladGreen - Sure, the OP made a bad suggestion in his question. If his intent is to remove duplicates that are close to each other then rounding isn't the answer. The OP should be told that.

Answer (score 4):

Using `Round` can create a situation where two numbers, even though incredibly close to each other, can end up being considered distinct.

Take this example:

```
var Mylist = new []
{
    new { X = 1.0000051, Y = 1.0 },
    new { X = 1.0000049, Y = 1.0 },
    new { X = 1.1, Y = 1.0 },
    new { X = 1.0, Y = 1.005 },
};
```

The first two values are very close - in fact they differ in the 6th decimal place.

By what if we run this code:

```
var result =
    Mylist
        .GroupBy(x => new
        {
            X = Math.Round(x.X,5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero),
            Y = Math.Round(x.Y,5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
        })
        .Select(g => g.First())
        .ToList();
```

The result is:

[image: result1]

The rounding has allowed these two values to be kept.

The correct approach is to filter by distance. If a subsequent value is within a threshold of the previous values it should be discarded.

Here's the code that does that:

```
var threshold = 0.000001;
Func<double, double, double, double, double> distance
    = (x0, y0, x1, y1) =>
        Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x1 - x0, 2.0) + Math.Pow(y1 - y0, 2.0));

var result = Mylist.Skip(1).Aggregate(Mylist.Take(1).ToList(), (xys, xy) =>
{
    if (xys.All(xy2 => distance(xy.X, xy.Y, xy2.X, xy2.Y) >= threshold))
    {
        xys.Add(xy);
    }
    return xys;
});
```

Now if we run that on the `Mylist` data we get this:

[image: result2]

This is a better ideal for removing duplicates.

Comment: cool :) I like this. (And by the way what I suggested is not the `GroupBy` but the `Distinct`

Comment: That's really a good point that I had to learn. Thanks, @Enigmativity for this clarification, I will consider this in eliminating non-necessary intermediate extra points! when it implement it, I will write here back.